# Use SFDC instead of spreadsheet

Tags: salesforce, spreadsheet, accounting

Below is a spreadsheet where I would like to transfer to SFDC.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArjzY2lGAEAFdHdoc1ZERDlVRHZBRzlxRlJPQ0RPSVE&usp=sharing

Basically, I would like to insert the daily sales and expenses.

Once I input the daily sales and expenses, the weekly and monthly sales would be generated automatically.

Is this possible with SFDC?  Or is there a simpler solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try dataloader.io  It is free for a single task.
Export the fields you want to upload to so you get a header with all the IDs.  Then map your speadsheet to these fields and upload them.

There is also salesforce's dataloader app:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=installing_the_data_loader.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dataLoader/

**Be sure to test in your sandbox/dev org first.  Also only upload one or two rows the first time as a test!**

Answer (score 0):

Use **apex dataloader** to export an excel or CSV files into SFDC  Object as records.
 While exporting choose this file as input and map the fileds as required.

Thanks,

Naveen

[autorabit](http://www.autorabit.com)